# Add file from working directory into code

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Is there a 'shortcut' way to add a file in the code in `pycharm`? I have this structure everything is in a folder called '`myFolder`' that you  cannot see on the picture.

[image]

Using e.g. `Visual Code` I was able to reference the file like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('in/test_DS.csv', sep=';', encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

is there a similar way in `Pycharm` or do I have to do full reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no such feature, but there is a corresponding feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33254 which is **In Progress** and expected to be in 2019.2 version.